# Screen communication from a 8K RAM

Tags: computers, ram

I have recently completed the [Nand2Tetris 1](https://www.coursera.org/learn/build-a-computer) on Coursera which lets you create a basic computer. For a while now I have been trying to physically implement the things I learned to create a fully functional 16-bit computer. One thing I haven`t been able to figure out is how to implement a screen.

The course has told me how to write the values to be written to the screen on in a 8k Ram chip. Each register in the ram cab hold 16 bits. Each bit corresponds to a pixel. if the bit = 1 the pixel is black, if the bit is zero the pixel is white.

The firs register represents the first 16 pixels from the top right, the next register represents the next 16 bits from where the last register left off. When  line is completed, it continues to the next line. This continues until the entire screen has been filled, in which case it repeats the entire process from the top.

[here](http://nand2tetris.org/lectures/PDF/lecture%2005%20computer%20architecture.pdf) on p.13 is a diagram to make it easier to understand.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is this how a normal screen works?
2. How do I write the values in the RAM onto the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's roughly how a normal screen works: that piece of RAM is called a *framebuffer*.

What's not shown is that there will be another piece of hardware reading from the RAM and refreshing the screen. For VGA video, this involves turning the digital value into an analogue value at precise times and sending out the pixels in sequence, corresponding to the path traced by the electron gun in a CRT display. "RAMDAC" is the term to look for here.

Various people have done VGA generation with microcontrollers, such as this page which also has some useful references: http://quinndunki.com/blondihacks/?p=955

Comment: It gets a little tricky, however, given that 8 kB is only 64 kbits, which would correspond to roughly a 256x256 array of pixels, which is not enough to fill a VGA screen. The readout logic would have to "map" one bit from the RAM to multiple adjacent pixels on the screen in order to get a full-screen display, or generate some wide black borders around the edges of the screen.

Comment: Yeah, the linked PDF talks about a "256x512 B&W screen", which has to be an error. The ZX spectrum has 256x192. http://whatnotandgobbleaduke.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/zx-spectrum-screen-memory-layout.html

Comment: No, it isn't a typo. The screen memory is described as "an 8K 16-bit RAM chip", which is 16 kB, or 128 kbits, which is enough for a 512x256 binary display. I misread it as 8 kB when I wrote my first comment. However, the paper is discussing a *simulation* of a computer, and doesn't deal with the reality of physically scanning a keyboard or transferring the display data to a real screen.